# Cannot import ksoap2 to Android Studio

Tags: java, import, android-studio, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I just added  ksoap2 (actually it is ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar) to app/libs folder.
Also I have used the Project Structure window to add ksoap2 to the Dependencies tab.

the Build.Gradle has this section

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

Anyway I cannot import ksoap2 like

```
import org.ksoap.*;
```

Any clue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490772/failed-to-implement-ksoap2-android-assembly-3-6-0-within-android-studio solved my problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first, You should remove ksoap in Project Structure and do the steps bellow.
I have same problem and here is the way which work for me.
1st: Make folder libs in app/libs.
2nd: Copy ksoap.jar to this folder.
3rd: right click to Jar file and chose add as library.
From now, you can import ksoap2 to your code normally.
You can create an object from ksoap2, the library will be imported automatically.
Ex: type **SoapObject tempResponse = null**

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
```

P/s: You should use ksoap library latest is 3.6.0, should not use 3.4.0 ;)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHEvI_G6UtI

Comment: When you add it like a library which option we have to select?

Comment: If it ask you to confirm, please confirm them. Using yes/ok/... or any similar button. Just confirm.

Answer (score 3):

Just put

```
 implementation 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2'
in dependencies
```

and

```
maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
```

in repositories

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! I user jar-file before. )