# Failed to implement ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.0 within Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ksoap2, onvif

I am working on a ONVIF Android application project. I found out that it is based on web services and SOAP protocol.
Afterward, I downloaded the ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.0.JAR library in order to use the classes such as SoapObject. I put it under libs directory and set it as Library.

The problem is that I cannot import org.ksoap2.SoapObject;
Please help !

[image: Here is my dependencies in gradle file]

Comment: Same problem with ksoap 2.4 within android studio 3.5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I imported it like this:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1'
}
```

and

```
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works fine. No need to copy/paste any library file.